# Angular 1.0.7: Https api call in $resource

Tags: angularjs, rest, https

I have an Angular1.0.7 webapp that is making calls to an rails API listening in an specific port. We want to migrate to HTTPS protocol for security reasons. Is it possible to "autodetect" the protocol in the resource api call?

Example resource call:

```
function($resource, SERVER_URL){          
        var languages =
         $resource('http://' + SERVER_URL +'/:action/:id', {action:'languages', id: '@id'}, {...
```

I have read somewhere you can just call like this, to autodetect the protocol:

```
$resource('/:action/:id', {action:'languages', id: '@id'}
```

However, my api listes in an specific port, so I need to tell it somehow.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$resource('//' + SERVER_URL +'/:action/:id', { ...` without adding `http:` at the beginning?

Comment: Ouch, I thought I did. You are right, in case you want to answer.

Comment: Will add as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try [scheme relative URL](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-url-string) like:

`$resource('//' + SERVER_URL +'/:action/:id', { ...`

without `http:` at the beginning.